# Not getting the hang of TASKs and WAIT in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, openehr

I have a stack of calls to a web api that  need to be called asynchronously. I have never used the aysnc.

I have created a simple test console program, along the lines of :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassOne xx = new ClassOne();
        var v1 = xx.DummyTask();
    }
}
```

With the class defined as :

```
namespace GHTest.classes
{
    public class ClassOne
    {
        GitHubClient client;

        public ClassOne()
        {
           client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("OMHSite"));
        }

        public async Task<string> DummyTask()
        {
            Task<Repository> task = client.Repository.Get("openEHR", "CKM-mirror");
            task.Wait();

            var myResult = task.Result;
            return myResult.FullName;
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio states I should use the "await" operator as currently this code will run synchronously. Where does the await operator go?

Furthermore if the following statement throws an exception, how do I catch that in the task

```
client.Repository.Get("openEHR", "CKM-mirror");
```

Comment: Assuming you've searched for something like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+async+console your code looks strange... Please update your post with links you've used to learn about `async`/`await` usage in console apps so it is easier to understand what you don't know/need help with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`task.Wait();` is redudant, the call to `task.Result` would wait implicitly.

Here is your method rewritten to use `await`.

```
Task<Repository> task = client.Repository.Get("openEHR", "CKM-mirror");
var myResult = await task;

return myResult.FullName;
```

You don't need `.Result` either as the type of `await` on a `Task<T>` is `T`.

On the subject of exception handling you will need to do a `try`/`catch` around the `await` (or `Result` in your original code). As that is when the exception will be rethrown. Note that this is only true if the exception is thrown in the `Task`, in theory the `Get` function itself could throw which would have to be caught there.

Also note that since you are returning an `async` you can choose to catch the exception wherever you `await` (or `Result`) the call.

Finally don't forget that if you don't `await` the result of `DummyTask` your task may not complete (or `Result`).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassOne xx = new ClassOne();
    var v1 = xx.DummyTask();
    var resultV1 = v1.Result; //Forces the execution of v1 by requesting its result.
}
```

Comment: I changed the code as suggested removing the task.Wait(); 
When the calling programs gets the response from the method the task is still waiting for activation, even though the "await" statement has been added.

If I add the  task.Wait(); back again then it works....

Comment: @BENBUNCoder You also need to `await` or `Wait()` the result of `DummyTask()`; that is, in your `static void Main(string[] args)` you need to do: `ClassOne xx = new ClassOne(); Task<string> task = xx.DummyTask(); task.Wait(); var v1 = task.Result; Console.WriteLine(v1);`.